# How to select the date from Excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a question about excel. What will be the formula for selecting a data for one criteria. The criteria will be the last day of the month. For example, from this table:

[image]

I need to choose automatically the number for 31 january 1994, and after this I need to select the number for the last day of the next month. I have to select the data for each month for 22 years.

Answer (score 0):

It's a bit unclear what you mean by "choose automat the number" and "select the number", and you didn't tag with your Excel version. But, if you have Excel 2007 or later, perhaps this will help.

Let's assume your first "Date" value (`17-Jan-1994`) is located in cell `A2`.

1. In cell `C2`, add the following formula, which will return `TRUE` if the value in `A2` is the last day of the month (otherwise it will return `FALSE`):

   ```
   =EOMONTH(A2, 0) = A2
   ```
2. Formula-copy cell `C2` all the way down to the last row in the table.
3. On the Ribbon's "Data" tab, in the "Sort & Filter" section, click the "Filter" button (it looks like a funnel).
4. Click the dropdown that now exists in column `C`, click the "FALSE" item so as to remove its checkmark, and then click the "OK" button.
5. Your table will be filtered so as to display only rows where the "Date" value represents the last day of the month. You can now select the values in column `B` and copy/paste them, or do whatever you like with them.

Result:

[image]